# Disable multiselect cell off tableview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

If i tap two different cell with two finger at a time in tableview, then didSelectRowAtIndexPath call two times. However i want to disable this. I tried with self.restaurantTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;. It doesn't work for me. The i tried with self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO; but in the details action, i need to push another view. So i need to make the self.view.userInteractionEnabled = yes; after the push. Both occasion, the view has been pushed double times. So what should i do in this situation? Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem. The system interprets it as one after another tap. So you should response correctly on every tap on every cell. But if you don't want the cells to be selected, just set "allowsSelection" on table view to NO.